# Compare Procrustes values

Tags: data-transformation, goodness-of-fit, spatial, procrustes-analysis

I have two sets of spatial data which underwent a transformation. I'd like to compare the effect of the transformation on two sets of data to test the hypothesis that the transformation had a larger effect on one set of data. I planned to use a Procrustes test to evaluate the effect of the transformation. The program I'm using returns a disparity statistic.

Is there a way to compare the two disparity statistics?

Comment: Are these two transformations on the same original "true" set of spatial coordinates? Another analysis may be bidimensional regression - see [Tobler, 1994](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1538-4632.1994.tb00320.x/pdf). There you could compared the sets of coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a [PROcrustean Randomization TEST](http://labs.eeb.utoronto.ca/jackson/ecoscience.pdf) (PROTEST), which makes use of permutations in order to assign a significance to the match of your in this case spatial datasets.

So what you could do is run two PROTEST-analyses, one with and one without transformation and see which scenario returns the highest statistical significance.

An alternative might be to use the [Mantel-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel_test), which already assigns a p-value to your match. Of course, the Mantel test also has its drawbacks (see for example [here](http://jackson.eeb.utoronto.ca/files/2012/09/protest-vs-mantel.pdf).  )